# Googlesheets - Get the sum of a special string column

Tags: google-sheets

How can I sum up a sheet with many columns looks like below (list 3 column for example):

```
|-------+-----------|
|     1 | HKD 2,010 |
|-------+-----------|
|     2 | HKD 1,010 |
|-------+-----------|
|     3 | HKD 2,020 |
|-------+-----------|
| Total | HKD 5,050 |
|-------+-----------|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in B1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(sum(value(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "[^' ']*$"))))
```

Comment: Neson Oh, my example is 3 elems, but I wish to process many elems. So maybe it's not proper to list every elem there!

Comment: Great, it's exactly what I want.